# Writing/Reading the contents in a Memory Stream instead of File Stream in C++

Tags: c++, fstream, ifstream, memorystream, ofstream

I want to write and read the contents to a **memory stream** instead of any **file stream** like fstream, ifstream or ofstream. So that all the contents which should be written in a file should be there in the Memory so that it can be transferred easily with fast access.

**How should I do this implementation in C++?**

Here what I meant to say:-
I will open the ofstream and start writing the content in the file before it saves and closed, I want to read all the content till added in fout in the StringStream, like the below.
And finally I all the content are in my String Stream and file wouldn't be created as I will not use the fout.close().

```
ofstream fout(FileWritePath, ios_base::out);

fout << "Blahh Blahh.....\n\n";
fout << "Name: Abhishek\n";
fout << "Age: 43";

stringstream Readbuffer;
Readbuffer << fout.rdbuf();

string ReadFullstring = Readbuffer.str();
cout << ReadFullstring << endl;
```

Comment: [`std::stringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream)?

Comment: I don't know is there any memory stream available in C++. So my main motive is to write in the memory stream. If stringstream does this work then please provide me short code.
Thanks @G.M.

Comment: Please see the [example](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream/basic_stringstream#Example) in the link provided.  If that's not sufficient please add details to your question to clarify your actual requirements.

Comment: @G.M. Please see the above explanation. Please see

Answer (score 0):

You answered your own question:
If you want to store the values in some data structure that behaves like a filestream, use a [`stringstream`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/) (from the `sstream`-package):

```cpp
std::ostringstream buf;

buf << "Blahh Blahh.....\n\n";
buf << "Name: Abhishek\n";
buf << "Age: 43";

std::cout << buf.str() << std::endl;
```

will then yield, as expected, to:

```
Blahh Blahh.....

Name: Abhishek
Age: 43
```

<kbd>[Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/P87358)</kbd>

Comment: Yes, Thank you. So much.
I have seen yesterday itself. But thank you for your prompt reply.